# MVC autocomplete how do I get my list of items into an object to return to Json

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, linq, autocomplete

I am returning a List from the database. I need to return an Object for the Json method.
Any Ideas. I am new to linq and MVC.

```
public ActionResult Autocomplete(string term)
        {
            var names = itemsRepository.GetListItemNames(term);
              ///linq code to get my name object out
            return Json(names, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: Looks correct, what is itemsRepository.GetListItemNames(term) returning?

Comment: Its returning a List<items>  I wrote this...I am going to try it out.  var getNames = names.Select(c => c.ItemName);

Comment: What's the actual problem? Is there an exception or is nothing being passed back to your view when you do the autocomplete call?

Comment: I got it work. There were no exceptions. I was passing a list when I should be passing an object from that list. I used linq to fix it. Since I am new if you have other ideas ..I open to them.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult Autocomplete(string term)
        {
            var names = itemsRepository.GetDistinctListItemNames(term);
            var getNames = names.Select(c => c.ItemName);

            return Json(getNames, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Since Json needed an object and I was querying a List , so this simple linq select was able to get the right object which was itemName.